# Devanagari and Latin Characters in Spacemacs org-mode layer

Tags: polyglossia, emacs, org-mode, devanagari

I use spacemacs org-mode and try to create a pdf file with Devanagari and Latin Characters through Latex.

Here is my unsuccessful approach:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{polyglossia}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_COMPILER: lualatex
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \setmainlanguage{english}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
#+LATEX_HEADER:   \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Noto Serif Devanagari}

#+begin_latex
\begin{sanskrit}
#+end_latex

श्रीमत्परमहंस परिव्राजकाचार्यवर्य।
#+begin_latex
\end{sanskrit}
#+end_latex

śrīmatparamahamsa
```

The pdf will be compiled without the devanagari characters. Any clue?